# jquery/javascript menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("li.level2").hide();
    $("li.level3").hide();

    $("ul.navigation").delegate("li.level1", "click", function() {
        $("li.level2").toggle().siblings("li.level3").hide();;
    });

    $("ul.navigation").delegate("li.level2", "click", function() {
        $("li.level3").toggle();
    });
});
```

I'm using this script to make a drop down menu for my page in jquery, but currently when you click on a level1 list it opens up every level1, when i just want to open the one that was clicked on. ie. it is doing this when i click on the first 1:

```
1

    2

1

    2
```

when i want it to do this

```
1

    2

1
```

I understand you can use the $this function to only open the one selected, but i am unsure how to implement it and whenever i try (this).next it only opens the next one when

I included an active page with styling to make it easier to interpret: http://jsfiddle.net/K6TSv/1045/

thanks for your help in advanced, this has been driving my head on.

Comment: Add the word 'this' without the quotes before the selector in the click binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the clicked item using `$(this)` and then get the next level2 items and show that.

```
$("ul.navigation").delegate("li.level1", "click", function() {
    var item=$(this);
    item.next(".level2").toggle();      
});
```

jsfiddle Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/K6TSv/1046/

If i were doing this. I would create a hierarchical HTML markup to handle this which will make things easy

**EDIT : As per the comment ( Markup changed!!!)**

If you want to select elements based on some selection criteria unitl some element, Use [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function.

```
$(this).nextUntil(".level1",".level2").toggle();
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/K6TSv/1072/

Comment: shyju i spoke prematurely haha, um when implementing the .next function its only opening the next menu item even when there are other items in the level ie. only opening one 2 when it should open both http://jsfiddle.net/K6TSv/1065/

Comment: so when i click on the 1 i want to show all the level 2s until the next 1

Comment: That is what the example i gave you does. What problem you face now ?

Comment: when you click on the first 1, it only shows one of the level 2s not both of them. http://jsfiddle.net/K6TSv/1065/

Comment: @user1448093 I see only one level 2 item under the first level 1. What you mean by **both** ?

Comment: if you look at the html, there are two level2s under the level one, ie. two submenus. im trying to get it to show both of them. ie the two level2s that appear before the next level 1 instead of just one of them. ie. 1 2 2 1 when you click on the first 1 instead of 1 2 1

Comment: @user1448093: That markup was not in in the initial question. I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: sorry shyju that has done the trick! do you have a paypal i can donate too?

Comment: @user1448093: You are welcome. You do not need to pay me. :) Instead you can simply give me an upvote (by clicking on the UP arrow near to the answer) and Mark this as the answer. :)